# mysql - selecting rows horizontally

Tags: mysql

I have this mysql table (as below image). I want to select id's grouped by id

where:
datakey = label and datavalue = is_member 
and, at the same time where:
datakey = since and datavalue = 20110204

So the end result should just be **105**.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Please edit your post to include at least one of your attempts at a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to achieve this without join.  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca8d6/1

```
SELECT t.id
FROM table_name t
WHERE (datakey = 'Label' AND datavalue = 'is_member') OR (datakey = 'Since' AND datavalue = '20110204')
GROUP BY t.id
HAVING COUNT(datakey) = 2;
```

Comment: unfortunately this wont work as i need the query to work for both statements not either...

Comment: This query will return for both.  There may be OR in the query but with the use of GROUP BY and HAVING, this query will return exactly what you want.  Or am I overlooking something here?

Comment: Ah I see, the HAVING statement ensures that there are 2 rows in the result, thus matching the number of WHERE statements.

Answer (score 1):

this should get what you need

```
SELECT
  a.id
FROM
  some_table AS a
  JOIN some_table AS b
    ON
      b.id = a.id
WHERE
  a.datakey = 'Label'
    AND
  a.datavalue = 'is_member'
    AND
  b.datakey = 'Since'
    AND
  b.datavalue = '20110204'
```

The assumption here is, that the field `id` references the same dataset.

Comment: removed that particular typo ;)